# Swift ios is it possible to swipe between images using UIImageView

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview, slider

First off, I am new to swift / ios.

In my viewcontroller I have a UIImageView, in that I load in an URL form an extrenal API in order to show an image.

What I want to do now is to to be able to swipe between image(s), so I dont want a pageviewcontroller.

Is this possible to do with a UIImageView?
If so please share any example / github library, it would help alot.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't really swipe between images using an image view. You could, however, put an image view inside another view and swipe/pan to slide between images. That is a fair amount of work to implement.

You should not be so quick to reject `UIPageViewController`. It has a slide style as an alternative to the page curl style. It handles what you want to do beautifully. Setting up a page view controller is a lot like setting up a table view or a collection view.

Do a search in the Xcode help system on "PhotoScroller". That will point you to a demo app that provides a UI for scrolling through a series of images. It handles tiling of large images so it's more than you need, but it serves as an example of the UI I think you are after.

Comment: Thanks, the Photoscroller was a great resource but I dont think UIPageViewController fit my needs. If I got it right a PageControllerView works as a standalone view, or is it possible to place a PagecontrollerView inside a viewcontroller? What I want to do is pretty much like on the ebay/amazon app. When you click on an item you are taken from the tableview to the viewcontroller "Item details page" On that page there is a title and some information about the item. I also have an image at the top displaying the item, but I want to be able to swipe between images instead. Not in modal way

Comment: A page view controller is a view controller. You can use it full-screen, or you can embed it inside another view controller by adding a container view and control-dragging from the container view to your child view controller (the page view controller in this case) to create an embed segue.

Comment: After taking a look I understand that I can do this by either prepareForSegue or using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. Is there any pros / cons between them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to use segues the segue must be defined in your Storyboard. I find that my storyboard gets cluttered with segue connections that are hard to sort out. For complex projects I sometimes use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` and then display it with code rather than using segues

Comment: Alright then, I couldnt really get it working with prepareForSegue but I think I sorted it out by using initiateViewControllerWithIdentifier instead. I had this as a refrence: http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/2/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial
Anyways, once more thank you. I learned something new and will def read on about it :)